# Static function prototypes in kernel modules

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I'm reading `LKM` development manual and faced the following example when [writing a device driver](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x569.html):

```
/*  
 *  Prototypes - this would normally go in a .h file
 */
int init_module(void);
void cleanup_module(void);
static int device_open(struct inode *, struct file *);
static int device_release(struct inode *, struct file *);
static ssize_t device_read(struct file *, char *, size_t, loff_t *);
static ssize_t device_write(struct file *, const char *, size_t, loff_t *);
```

The thing I was confused by was that it is proposed to put `static` **non**-`inline` declarations into a header file. What is the reason for that?

If we are **not** supposed to use these functions related to the driver anywhere except than in the

```
struct file_operations fops = {
    .open = device_open,
    .release = device_release,
    .read = device_read,
    .write = device_write
};

static int init_module(void){
    int register_result = register_chrdev(&fops);
    //...
}
```

during module initialization then we can simply put their static definitions right here avoiding prototypes declaration. Otherwise they should (should?) be declared with external linkage.

Comment: They are declared static to avoid polluting the kernel namespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is absolutely no needs to put `static` non-`inline` declarations into a separate header file.

In case of very complex driver definitions of `device_*` methods could be arranged into different source files (and definition of `file_operations` structure could be arranged into its own source file too), but in that case `static` specifier should be dropped.